# Vlookup alternative for multiple results

Tags: excel, vlookup, spreadsheet

I have a workbook with two sheets, the first of which is a blank form where I need to return multiple results (cases & due dates) for each lookup. Column A has an Item # listed. Each item has multiple cases, which have different due dates. the items and due dates are in columns B & C of the second sheet. I can use a vlookup, but it will only return one of the results and I need to capture every case on the way. I'm very bad with nested formulas/etc., what can I use for this? Pics are a simplified version. The actual workbook has several hundred entries and the data I am pulling from has extraneous item #s sometimes so manually sorting or copying/pasting is not an option. Pics below explain better. Thanks!

[image: Picture # 1]

[image: Picture #2]

Comment: does your version have FILTER?

Comment: BTW, no formula will allow it to expand and contract.  You would need to have enough blank rows between each Item to exceed the most it could ever be.

Comment: I'm fine with adding blank rows. Unfortunately I don't have FILTER or I would use that.

Comment: I'm not sure of exactly what you want to do, but here are two techniques which might be useful: Insert two columns A and B to the left; populate A2 with =if(C2="",A1,C2). And in B2 = A2&"_"& D2. Drag both down. B is then a full key which can be LOOKUPed on.